# Annotation for non-model organism

Tags: bioinformatics, rna

I want to annotate data while analyzing transcritpome data using DESeq2 , usually Biomart R-package (https://www.bioconductor.org/packages/release/bioc/html/biomaRt.html) does the needful , but for non-model organism for which link to Biomart R package is not available seems troublesome, any way to use the custom annotation file( I have one annotation file obtained from Uniprot) or any other alternative to do so?

Comment: Can you elaborate? DESeq2 takes count data where the row names are labeled sequence features and allows you to test for differential expression. If you want to associate an annotation with a given sequence you don't need DESeq2, either the sequence features can be matched to the annotation or you need to go back to how the transcripts were assembled.

Comment: What kind of annotation file are you looking for? Can you clarify a bit on what exactly do you intend to do?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is a question about computation (how should I accomplish X in R), not about biological concepts.